# Transposing the column in pandas and also repeating the value of each row (number of column times)

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry for the title as it is confusing. I have a pandas dataframe as below.

```
date     A    B
jan 1    4    5
jan 2    6    8
...     ...   ...
```

What I wanted to do is transpose the dataframe (which I know df.T) and also needed the resulting dataframe to look like below

```
col1   date   value
A      jan 1  4
A      jan 2  6
B      jan 1  5
B      jan 2  8
```

Please advice and thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.melt`:

```
print(pd.melt(df, 'date'))
```

Or use `df.melt`:

```
print(df.melt('date'))
```

They both output:

```
    date variable  value
0  jan 1        A      4
1  jan 2        A      6
2  jan 1        B      5
3  jan 2        B      8
```

Comment: wow I never thought of Melt...Thanks :) .it works...

Comment: @python_interest Your welcome :P `melt` is magic :-)

Comment: @python_interest Accept it too!